# How can I change the color of <> tags on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I recently changed my color theme in VisualStudio Code, I like everything from the theme except for the light purple color of the <> tags, they clash with the pink. How can I change them so they're a different color, preferable just a darker purple. Btw the theme im using is called Tokyo Night Storm.

Here's an image showing how the angle brackets are currently colored:
[image: <> tags]

I tried going into my settings.json couldn't find exactly what to write.

Comment: I found this on internet maybe it could help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: @amel that link is for Visual Studio, but this question is about Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` action to open [the Scope Inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector). Then click on the token you want to inspect. Then find out its textmate scopes. In this case, the opening angle bracket is:

```
punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html
meta.tag.structure.html.start.html
text.html.derivative
```

Pick an appropriate textmate scope, and then use it in a token colour customization like so:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Tokyo Night Storm]": {
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope":"punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000",
                "fontStyle": "bold"
            }
        },{
            "scope":"punctuation.definition.tag.end.html",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000",
                "fontStyle": "bold"
            }
        }],
    }
},
```

See also [the docs for creating your own colour theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme).